# KeyError when trying to access request.meta's key in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

Here is the code of a simple spider:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.http import Request

class AzS(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'azs'
    allowed_domains = ["******"]
    start_urls = [
        "*********" 
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths = ("""//*[@id="yearList"]""")), callback = 'year', follow = True), # years at start url
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths = ("""/html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul""")), callback = 'model', follow = True), # model
    )


    # start url with years list
    def year(self, response):
        yr = response.url.split('=')[-1][2:4]
        request = Request(response.url,
                          callback = self.model)
        request.meta['yr'] = yr
        return request


    # the page of the year with models list 
    def model(self, response):
        print response.meta['yr']
```

and when executed, this code produces this error:

```
File "xxxxxxxxxx.py", line 33, in model
            print response.meta['yr']
        exceptions.KeyError: 'yr'
```

I'm not able to figure out what causes this error, so any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have two rules and whenver the second rule become true obviously some requests will be triggered and from there the response is getting at `model`, in that case you are not setting any `meta` data with key `'yr'`. This might be the root cause of your error.

Either you can use some `try - except` or try to access the key using `get()`, ie, `response.meta.get('yr', 'your_value')`. If that `key` is not found it will take `your_value` as the value.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing at multiple rules issue; try-except and dict.get() are not the solution, because I need to pass the data between callbacks. Any suggestions?

Comment: Oh..great answer jithin. You are awsome :), +1

Comment: but `hasattr` is the best approach than `try-except`

Comment: if you could post the start-url it will be easy to find the solution.